# Слот в QObject::connect не хочет выполняться в потоке объекта, который принимает сигнал

Tags: c++, qt, сигналы-слоты, qthread

Тяжелый класс для работы с большими директориями унаследован от QThread. В конструкторе указано только `: QThread(nullptr)`. Вся логика лежит в перегруженном методе `run()`, который запускается в новом потоке после создания объекта и вызова родительского публичного метода `Thread::start()`.

В методе `run()` вывожу в консоль id потока, затем в исполняемом методе. Потоки разные. Таким образом объект, выведенный для работы в отдельный поток, фактически в своем потоке ничем не занимается, а соединения сигналов/слотов к нему являются блокирующими для вызывающего потока.

```
QObject::connect(mainThreadLogic, &MainClass::do, anotherObjectDerivedFromQThread, &Another::do);
```

Пробовал переносить это соединение в `run()` объекта, унаследованного от QThread, но результат прежний.

UPD. Пример:

```
class HeavyJob : public QThread
{
public:
    HeavyJob() : QThread(nullptr) {}
    void run() override; // пустой внутри

public slots:
    void do()
    {
    // Реализация в cpp-файле, но для простоты приведена тут
        QThread::sleep(10); // пример тяжелой блокирующей операции
    }
};

HeavyJob* heavy = new HeavyJob;
connect (someObject, &SomeObject::someSignal, heavy, &HeavyJob::do);
heavy->start();

// При сигнале someSignal() объекта someObject
// слот do() объекта heavy выполняется в потоке someObject, 
// а не в специально созданном потоке объекта heavy. 
// В этом гвоздь программы.
```

Comment: мало понятно, что делаешь и в чём проблема... [mcve] сможешь набросать?

Comment: @Fat-Zer добавил

Comment: `void run() override; // пустой внутри` если метод run завершается, то поток завершает свою работу.

Answer (score 1):

Не знаю на сколько правильно, но у меня вот так получилось:

```
class HeavyJob : public QThread
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    HeavyJob()
        : QThread(nullptr)
    {}
    void run() override { exec(); }

public slots:
    void doAction()
    {
        qDebug() << __FUNCTION__ << " | Thread Id:" << QThread::currentThreadId();
        QThread::sleep(2); // пример тяжелой блокирующей операции
    }
};
```

...

```
HeavyJob *job = new HeavyJob();
job->moveToThread(job);
job->start();
connect(this, &MainWindow::emitSignal, job, &HeavyJob::doAction);
```

Вывод:

```
 Main thread: 0x3030
 HeavyJob::doAction  | Thread Id: 0x545c
```

В данном случае даже не обязательно унаследоваться от QThread, можно сделать согласно вот этой [доке](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthread.html#details)

Comment: `job->moveToThread(job);` это лишнее

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо за советы.

Вопрос решился указанием типа подключения `Qt::QueuedConnection`, который указывается пятым аргументов в `Object::connect()`.

Полезную информацию нашел [тут](http://doc.crossplatform.ru/qt/4.7.x//threads-qobject.html):

> Автоматическое соединение (Auto Connection) (по умолчанию) Если сигнал испускается в потоке, с которым объект-получатель имеет родство, то поведение такое же, как и при прямом соединении. В противном случае, поведение аналогично соединению через очередь."
> Прямое соединение (Direct Connection) Слот вызывается немедленно при отправке сигнала. Слот выполняется в потоке отправителя, который не обязательно является потоком-получателем.
> Соединение через очередь (**Queued Connection**) Слот вызывается, когда управление возвращается в цикл обработки событий в потоке получателя. Слот выполняется в потоке получателя.

Comment: в таком случае слот всё равно будет выполнятся в контексте исходного потока, просто его запуск будет отложен...

Answer (score 0):

Все слоты `QThread`'а исполняются в контексте того потока, в котором находится сам объект `QThread`. Обычно это исходный поток, в котором `QThread` и был создан.

Наследовать `QThread` нужно чуть чаще, чем никогда, а правильным решением в данном случае будет создать отдельный объект-работника, унаследованный от `QObject` и переместить его в отдельный поток:

```
class HeavyWorker : public QObject {
public slots:
    void do() {
        QThread::sleep(10); // пример тяжелой блокирующей операции
    }
};


// ...

QThread* thread = new QThread(this);
HeavyWorker* worker = new HeavyWorker(this);
worker->moveToThread(thread);

connect (someObject, &SomeObject::someSignal, worker, &HeavyWorker::do);

thread->start();
```

см. описание [`QThread`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthread.html#details)

Comment: `Наследовать QThread нужно чуть чаще, чем никогда,` наследование QThread это тоже нормальный метод

Comment: @AlexanderChernin, я не из тех, кто считает такой метод «абсолютно неправильным», но ИМХО единственная мотивация для его использования — создать свой eventLoop... если с объектом в отдельном потоке нужно асинхронно взаимодействовать — используй отдельно рабочего, как выше... если нужен единичный запуск отдельного действия — используй `QtConcurrent`...

Comment: А причем тут `абсолютно правильный`, он вполне себе рабочий, такой же как и остальные.

Answer (score 0):

Вообще, для таких задач есть специальный модуль [QtConcurrent](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtconcurrent-index.html)

В вашем же случае, при уже запущенном и ожидающем потоке, можно делать так:

```
class HeavyJob : public QThread
{

signals:
    void workStarted();
    void workFinished();
public:
    HeavyJob() : QThread(nullptr) {}
    void run() override {
        __action = true;

        QMutex mutex;        
        while(__action) {
            mutex.lock();
            waiter.wait(&mutex);

            if (!__action) {
                break;
            }

            emit workStarted();
            // Тяжелая задача
            emit workFisnished();

            mutex.unlock();
        }
    }
public slots:
    void do()
    {
        waiter.wakeAll();
    }

    void stop() {
        __action = false;
        waiter.wakeAll();
    }

private:
    QWaitCondition waiter;
    bool __action;
};
```

Теперь вы можете создать где-нибудь поток, сразу запустить его

```
HeavyJob* heavy = new HeavyJob;
heavy->start();
```

После запуска он встанет в ожидание на строчке `waiter.wait()` и далее, чтобы его разбудить для выполнения задачи, нужно вызвать слот `do`. Для прекращения работы потока - слот `stop()`